# How to load data from API?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I made this JavaScript (JQuery) to load the data from an API call but it gives me an `undefined`. This is how it looks:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Autocomplete for Person
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: urlReq+'/api/persons/1',
            success: function(response) {
                let modelArray = response;
                let dataModel = {};

                for (let i = 0; i < modelArray.length; i++) {
                    dataModel[modelArray[i].first_name] = null;
                    console.log('data is: '+modelArray[i].first_name);
                }

                $('input.autocomplete_person').autocomplete({
                    data: dataModel,
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

where my `urlReq+'/api/persons/1'` returns something like this:

```
{"452":{"id":452,"reference":"20190528155926096","first_name":"John","middle_name":"Smith","third_name":null,"family_name":"Doe"}}
```

but my problem is that my console gives me this: `data is: undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 {"452":{"id":452,"reference":"20190528155926096","first_name":"John","middle_name":"Smith","third_name":null,"family_name":"Doe"}}
```

This is not an array so you can’t iterate over it.

Comment: Yes that’s a JSON format but there is no array inside of that. Please update the response exactly as it comes from the API so I can help

Comment: Now the result is something like this: ```[{"id":1,"reference":"20190214134326044","first_name":"Alicia","middle_name":"Duncan","third_name":null,"family_name":"Frank"}]``` but i still get the undefined result.

Comment: Is it because i have more than a thousand data in my database?

Comment: You are doing something wrong then. console.log('data is: '+modelArray[i].first_name) should work

Comment: No it’s not because of that because the database didn’t fail and you received data from the API

Comment: It's now work fine, i just clear my browser history and cookies by the way thanks for pointing out about the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the for loop and just assign the response directly:

```
let firstName = response[0].first_name; // "John"
```

Comment: But i have more than 1000 records.